# Generated test sources not getting invoked as part of the build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-contract

Having:

- added Spring Cloud Contract plugin and configured it for `baseClassMappings` as well as `basePackageForTests`
- added Spring Cloud Contract verifier
- added required base classes for generated tests
- and defined `groovy` contract

successfully generates test sources (which pass when run directly e.g. from within the IDE) under `cdc/build/generated-test-sources/contracts/com/example/cdc/contract/verifier/tests/producer/practice`

But...

These generated test sources do not get invoked as part of the build e.g. `./gradlew clean build` meaning **I do not know if I have broken the contract until I run generated tests manually e.g. from the IDE**.

Have I missed a step?

Producer project: https://github.com/bilalwahla/cdc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Kotlin. We have an issue for adding source sets in Gradle better (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/872). Until then just set

```
sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += new File(project.buildDir, "generated-test-source").toString()
}
```

With this issue being closed (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/888), you can check out that the latest snapshots should work better for you.