# Unable to read a source file generated during annotation processing only when its in the test package

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

Banging my head against this for hours...

1. I have an annotation processor which outputs new java source files.
2. Those files are written to the standard Gradle (7.4.2) location e.g. `build/sources/annotationProcessor/java`
3. Files generated for classes annotated in the **main** package get put in `annotationProcessor/java/main`. Files generated for classes annotated in the **test** package get put into `annotationProcessor/java/test`

**The problem:** I can only use the java files output to `annotationProcessor/main` when compiling my tests. Any attempts to reference files generated in `annotationProcessor/test` cause `cannot find symbol` errors at build time.

**Setup:**

I'm using a completely stock Gradle 7.4.2 multi-projcest setup as created by `init`.

**Directory Structure:**

```
├── lib                           <-- this is where I'm using the annotation
│   ...
│   └── src/main/com/myproject
│         └── MyPojo.java         <-- this has an annotation on it
│   └── src/test/com/myproject
│         └── MyOtherPojo.java    <-- this has an annotation on it
│         └── MyTest.java         <-- Where I'm running the test
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── processor                     <-- Where my annotation processor code lives
│   ...
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

The `build.gradle` for `lib` is similarly stock *with one exception*: I've manually added the `build` dirs to my source sets:

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id("java")
}

group = "myproject"
version = "0.1"


repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")

    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")

    // this is my annotation processor
    implementation(project(":processor"))
    annotationProcessor(project(":processor"))
    testAnnotationProcessor(project(":processor"))
}

// NEW! 
// To read the annotation generated files at all, I've had 
// to manually add the build dir to my source sets. 
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("path\\to\\lib\\build\\generated\\sources\\annotationProcessor\\java\\main")
        }

    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir("path\\to\\lib\\build\\generated\\sources\\annotationProcessor\\java")
        }
    }
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**What's happening:**

When I run a test: my annotation processor kicks in. Finds the `MyPojo` (from main) and `MyOtherPOJO` (from test) classes that are annotated with my annotation, and generates a new helper files for each. They're put into `annotationProcessor/main` and `annotationProcessor/test` respectively.

Like this:

```
├── lib                           
│   ...
│   └── build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java
│         └── MyPojoHelper.java         <-- my generated class
│   └── build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/test
│         └── MyOtherPojoHelper.java    <-- my generated class
│   └── src
│       ...
```

So far so good.

I can use the generated files in `annotationProcessor/main` with no issue in my test file.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    generated.myproject.MyPojoHelper.someMethod("foo"); // works! 
}
```

However, if I try to do the exact same thing, but referencing a generated file in `annotationProcessor/test`, I fail while compiling the test package.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    generated.myproject.MyOtherPojoHelper.someMethod("foo"); // compile failure! 
}
```

**Error:**

```
error: package gen.myproj does not exist
        gen.myproj.MyOtherPojoHelper.someMethood("foo");
                  ^
```

**Explicitly adding the `annotationProcessor/test` to source sets does not fix the problem:**

This is the recommended solution in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547390/generated-test-sources-not-getting-invoked-as-part-of-the-build).

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("path\\to\\lib\\build\\generated\\sources\\annotationProcessor\\java\\main")
        }

    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir("path\\to\\lib\\build\\generated\\sources\\annotationProcessor\\java")
        }
    }
    // NEW! 
    // Adding the test path explicitly
    test {
        java {
            srcDir("path\\to\\lib\\build\\generated\\sources\\annotationProcessor\\java\\test")
        }
    }
}
```

Same behavior while running the tests. For some reason, these files cannot be recognized.

**I am completely stumped**.

Comment: Very nice description of your problem. :) First of all, you should be able to completly remove the `sourceSets` block. The source sets should support annotation processors by default. Besides that, your first srcDir for the test block (the one without the `\\test` suffix) was wrong anyway. I think you should also use forward slashes instead of backward slashes in Gradle. Finally, I noticed that the generated files are generated in `generated.myproject`, but the error message reports an issue with `gen.myproj`; Probably just a copy&paste-error when you prepared this example? How is it going?

Comment: Maybe the issue had the same root cause as [this other question of you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74749264/4967497)?