# How do you use a class that was generated by an annotation processor? It says package does not exist

Tags: java, javac, annotation-processing

I have the world's simplest annotation processor:

```java
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("deoplice.processor.MyAnnotation")
public class MySimpleProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {


    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        String src = "package foo.bar;\n\n" +
                "public class MyPojo {\n" +
                "\tpublic MyPojo() {}\n" +
                "}";

        HashSet<? extends Element> annotatedHandlers = HashSet.ofAll(roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class));
        try {
            FileObject fileObj = processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT, "", "MyPojo.java");
            File extensionsFile = new File(fileObj.toUri());
            FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(extensionsFile);
            BufferedOutputStream ss = new BufferedOutputStream(s);
            ss.write(src.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            ss.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When run, it spits out a class called `MyPojo.java` into the build directory. It's as plain as can be:

```java
package foo.bar;
public class MyPojo {
    public MyPojo() {}
}
```

I have a simple `main` method:

```java
package example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
    }
}
```

When I run `main`, the annotation processor, `MySimpleProcessor`, does its work and generates the file. It gets stored in the default Gradle build directory. Here's what everything looks like:

```
├── lib
│   ...
|   └── build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main
|        └── MyPojo.java  <- generated File
│   └── src/main/java/example
│         └── Main.java         
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── processor                     
│   ...
│   └── src/main/java/
|   └── MySimpleProcessor.java 
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

#### If I try to use the generated file, I get a compile error: package not found

```java
package example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new foo.bar.MyPojo(); // Trying to instantiate the object
        System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
error: package foo.bar does not exist
        new foo.bar.MyPojo(); 
                   ^
```

#### How do you use a class generated by an annotation processor?

I've tried adding my build dir to the source sets, but it has no effect.

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("path\\to\\my\\build\\generated\\sources\\annotationProcessor\\java\\main")

        }
    }
}
```

**What in the world am I missing here?**

Comment: you need to use `processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile("foo.bar.MyPojo")` instead of `processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT, "", "MyPojo.java")`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov oof.. I am not smart. That did it. Thank you so much!!